# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST (Works perfectly in the localhost)

Tags: laravel

I integrated a photo capture blade, which was supposed to store the captured image into the database after clicking the submit button. In fact It works nicely in the localhost, but giving the following error in the server "**Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.**"

I am sharing the codes from route :

```
Route::get('verification/capturePhoto','App\Http\Controllers\VerificationController@capturePhoto');

Route::post('verify','App\Http\Controllers\VerificationController@verify');
```

codes from the controller :

```
public function capturePhoto()
{
    return view('ui.pages.users.user.capturePhoto');
}

public function verify(Request $request){

    $img = $request->image;
    $folderPath = "uploads/";
  
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';
  
    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    Verification::create([
        'photo' => $fileName,
        'identity_number' => session('passport_number'),
        'identity_card_document' => session('upload_documents'),
        'user_id' =>session('user_session'),
         
    ]);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

code from the blade :

```
@extends('ui.layout.app')

@section('content')

<form method="POST" action="{{url('verify')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="my_camera"></div>
            <br/>
            <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
            <input type="hidden" name="image" class="image-tag">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
            <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User Id" class="form-control" 
            style="width:300px;margin-top:20px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <br/>

            <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


@endsection
```

Comment: Did you run ```php artisan cache:clear``` and ```php artisan route:cache``` after deploying?

Comment: no, I ran before deployment - how can I run after deployment ?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning to a named route:

```
Route::get('verification/capturePhoto','App\Http\Controllers\VerificationController@capturePhoto')->name('verify-photo');
```

```
return redirect(route('verify-photo'))->with('success', 'Photo Verified');
```

What about:

```
return redirect()->to('/');
```

or

```
return redirect()->to(route('verify-photo'));
```

Comment: even whan you use `return redirect()->back()`?

Comment: yes lol, you were suggesting to put return redirect()->back() in verify function, right ?

Comment: Does the laravel.log contain anything on it?

Comment: yes,sorry for the delayed answer : #0 /home/motfofvt/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/VerificationController.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/motfofvt/...', 55, Array)
#1 /home/motfofvt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\VerificationController->verify(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 /home/motfofvt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('verify', Array)

Comment: #3 /home/motfofvt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\VerificationController), 'verify')
#4 /home/motfofvt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 /home/motfofvt/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(693): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a form not working online though it was working just fine on my local servor, getting me the same message. I solved it by rearranging my routes order in web.php and changing form action by action="{{route(...)}} instead of a url.